# Identify this Bianchi as much info as possible please

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

Hi I have a bianchi of which I have the serial # starting with 6634xxxx if that helps identify year and/or model.

**excuse the mess in the background-- it looks bad sorry

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting bike - it doesn't look like a bianchi frame visually.   The fork looks more 80's Raleigh, as do the dropouts with the fender lugs.   Though the chainstays have a more elegant curve.    Its hard to see in photo, but do the seat tube and head tube really differ in angle that much?

Comment: Yeah, 80s bike.  Pretty generic for the era.